# How replace faceapi.fetchImage() and use a function that will load my image from the database and be used for Facial Recognition

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, face-recognition

I am creating a face-recognition system with javascript, PHP and MySQL. The problem I have is I don't know how I will load the image from the database and replace the fetchImage() for something on the disk or MySQL database. I am using XAMPP and localhost.

This is my PHP script:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE email = '$user'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);;

$num = $row['stud_num'];
$name = $row['full_name'];
$image = $row['img_name'];
$image_src = "upload/".$image;
```

then this is for the face recognition

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    const img = await faceapi.fetchImage(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WebDevSimplified/Face-Recognition-JavaScript/master/labeled_images/${label}/${i}.jpg`)
    const detections = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(img).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptor()
    descriptions.push(detections.descriptor)
}
```

I want to change the fetch image since the

Comment: What do you mean - "load from datanase"? If you are storing a path to image file - get it from the db and load in normal way. And if you are storing BLOBs with images'  bunaries - get it as array  and then work with it as like an image is already loaded (or save it to disk as temp file and ... (see above).